# Deploying Cloud Run and React App from same Firebase.json file

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-run

I want to use Firebase hosting and cloud run to deploy my stateless container that runs my backend, and I want to also deploy a React App under the same hosting for my front end. Is this possible?

It seems that unless I point public to 'build' for the React app then the front end won't load, but when I do that it can no longer find the backend code?

Here is my `firebase.json` file:

```json
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/",
        "destination": "/frontend/build/index.html"
      },
      {
        "source": "/api/**",
        "run": {
          "serviceId": "backend",
          "region": "australia-southeast1"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

My file structure is:

```
public:
 -- backend
 -- frontend
    -- build
```

Does anyone know if it is possible to deploy a React App front end and cloud run backend from the same firebase.json hosting file?

Comment: You can set up one or more Firebase Hosting sites in a single Firebase project. Since the sites are all in the same Firebase project, all the sites can access the other Firebase resources of the project. For more information you can refer to the https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/multisites